# Get logging output to /rosout using rclutils (writing a client library)

Tags: ros, rosout, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a ROS2 client library for SWI-Prolog.   Basic pub/sub works.  Next step is to get logging to work.  Calling `rcutils_log()` works fine for loging to the console, but nothing appears in `/rosout` or in `rqt`.   It doesn't seem to matter whether I leave the initialization to `RCUTILS_LOGGING_AUTOINIT` or call `rcutils_logging_initialize()`.  Controlling the level affects the output in the console, so the basics seem to work.   I tried with and without a creating a ROS node.   The subscription works fine and the node is visible in `rqt`.

Platform is Ubuntu 20.04 using ROS2 foxy.

Any clue, including clues on how to debug this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373537/get-logging-output-to-/rosout-using-rclutils-(writing-a-client-library)/) by [Jan Wielemaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/70511/jan-wielemaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a lot of searching in the rcl and rcutils sources and some gdb breakpoints, I got it working.   Key are

- Initialize logging right after creating the rcl context, notably **before** creating a node in this context.
- Use `rcl_logging_configure_with_output_handler()` with `rcl_logging_multiple_output_handler` as handler, also **before** creating a node.
- Make sure `options.enable_rosout` is `true` for `rcl_node_init()`.  This is by default the case, but it was set to `false` in my code based on `rclpy` (which I guess sets it somewhere else).

---

Originally posted by [Jan Wielemaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/70511/jan-wielemaker/) with karma: 36 on 2021-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-08-12**:
This is probably rather niche, but thanks @Jan Wielemaker for posting the solution. Saved my quite a bit of time.